# Issue with function that calculates probability

Tags: julia

I have a function that takes an input, being the number of people, and calculates the probability that those people will have the same randomly generated birthday. I am using a dictionary and a randomly generated array, and then looping that 5000 times. However there seems to be an issue as when I try to run the function I get an error: `ArgumentError: Dict(kv): kv needs to be an iterator of tuples or pairs`. How can I fix this? Thank you!!

```
function prob_same_bday(numpeople::Int64)
    samebday = 0
    for i = 1:5000

        arr1 = rand(1:365, 1, numpeople)

        d = Dict(arr1)
        for val in itr
            d[val] = get!(d, val, 0) + 1
            if get!(d, val, 0) > 1
                samebday = samebday + 1
            else
                continue
            i = i + 1
            end
        end
    end
    return samebday / 5000
end
```

Comment: The `i = i + 1` after `continue` will never get executed. Did you intend it to come after the `end` of the `if`?

Answer (score 1):

You need just a 1-dimensional arryay so it should be

```
arr1 = rand(1:365, numpeople)
```

Now I assume you want to store number of hits in a dictionary. You cannot transfer array to dictionary like this. You could for example do:

```
d = Dict(1:numpeople .=> 0)
```

Note that `d` would work as good as a `Vector`

Looks like a homework assignment so keep trying :=)

Comment: Found the issue, I had `for val in itr`, because I had copied this from another project of mine, but it needed to be `for val in arr1`, and it works just fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: and just `d = Dict()`